Responsive design with shapes and canvas with KonvaJS
Context
I have a page that allows the user to upload an image (e.g., floorplan) and then add custom circles (desks) and custom rectangles (zones) on top of that image. The shapes will collectively be referred to as "annotations". I then save the relative position and size of each of the shapes in the DB. Then, when they are meant to be displayed, I retrieve them from the DB and re-draw the shapes.
Problem
I tried to make the page responsive in terms of displaying the annotations, particularly for mobile phones. The issue is that the image is resized normally, but the annotations are not in the same location relative to the image. For example, I place a desk annotation on a specific part of the image. When I change the screen size, the image is resized, but the relative position of the annotation is changed (e.g. it is now above the original location)
What I have tried

Originally, I have used absolute referencing within the <Stage> component, but it did not work and I faced the same problem
I switched to absolute referencing by calculating the position and size of the annotations based on the image dimension, but I also faced the same problem of shifting shapes
Responsive canvas with React and Konva
https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Responsive_Canvas.html

The code
The minimum reproducible code will be quite long as there are many moving parts, but I will try to keep it brief
Annotation.jsx (this is the main page)
      <Flex direction="column" p={4} align="center">
        <VStack spacing={4} mb={4} width="80%">
          <ImageUploadComponent roomId={roomId} />
          <HStack spacing={4}>
            <DrawingToolbar />
            <SaveAnnotations roomId={roomId} imageDims={imageDims} />
          </HStack>
        </VStack>
        <Flex width="100%">
          <Box flex="3" display="flex" justifyContent="center">
            <AnnotationCanvas setImageDims={setImageDims} />
          </Box>
          <ShapeList />
        </Flex>
      </Flex>

AnnotationCanvas.jsx (this is the component that allows the user to place shapes on the image)
      <Stage
        width={canvasWidth}
        height={canvasHeight}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        ref={stageRef}
      >
        <Layer>
          <AnnotationImage
            imageSrc={imageSrc}
            canvasWidth={canvasWidth}
            canvasHeight={canvasHeight}
            setImageDims={handleSetImageDims} // Use the handler here
          />
          {shapes.map((shape, index) => {
            const isSelected =
              selectedShapes.includes(index) || selectedShapeIndex === index;

            return (
              <ShapeRenderer
                key={index}
                shape={shape}
                index={index}
                isSelected={isSelected} // Pass the isSelected prop to the ShapeRenderer
                onSelect={() => {
                  setSelectedShapes([index]);
                  dispatch(setSelectedShapeIndex(index));
                }}
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                onTransformEnd={handleTransformEnd}
              />
            );
          })}

          {selectionRect && (
            <Rect
              x={selectionRect.x}
              y={selectionRect.y}
              width={selectionRect.width}
              height={selectionRect.height}
              stroke="blue"
              dash={[4, 4]}
              listening={false}
            />
          )}
          {selectedShapeIndex !== null && (
            <TransformerComponent
              selectedShapeIndex={selectedShapeIndex}
              shapes={shapes}
              stageRef={stageRef}
              onDeselect={() => dispatch(setSelectedShapeIndex(null))}
            />
          )}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>

AnnotationImage.jsx (this is the image)
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Image as KonvaImage } from 'react-konva';

const AnnotationImage = ({ imageSrc, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, setImageDims }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [dims, setDims] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageSrc) {
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.src = imageSrc;
      img.onload = () => {
        const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
        let width, height;

        if (canvasWidth / canvasHeight > aspectRatio) {
          // Canvas is wider than the image
          height = canvasHeight;
          width = height * aspectRatio;
        } else {
          // Canvas is taller than the image
          width = canvasWidth;
          height = width / aspectRatio;
        }

        setDims({ width, height });
        setImageDims({ width, height });
        setImage(img);
      };
    }
  }, [imageSrc, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, setImageDims]);

  return image ? (
    <KonvaImage
      image={image}
      width={dims.width}
      height={dims.height}
      x={(canvasWidth - dims.width) / 2}
      y={(canvasHeight - dims.height) / 2}
    />
  ) : null;
};

export default AnnotationImage;

SaveAnnotations.jsx (this is where the logic for saving the position and size of annotations happen)
const saveAnnotations = async () => {
    dispatch(deselectShape()); // Deselect the shape before saving
    try {
      const zones = shapes.filter((shape) => shape.type === "zone");
      const desks = shapes.filter((shape) => shape.type === "desk");

      const annotationsData = {
        zones: zones.map((zone) => {
          const zoneDesks = desks.filter(
            (desk) =>
              desk.x >= zone.x &&
              desk.x <= zone.x + zone.width &&
              desk.y >= zone.y &&
              desk.y <= zone.y + zone.height
          );

          return {
            name: zone.name || `Zone in Room ${roomId}`,
            x_val: zone.x / imageDims.width, // Store as a ratio of the image width
            y_val: zone.y / imageDims.height, // Store as a ratio of the image height
            width: zone.width / imageDims.width, // Store as a ratio of the image width
            height: zone.height / imageDims.height, // Store as a ratio of the image height
            desks: zoneDesks.map((desk) => ({
              name: desk.name || `Desk in Zone`,
              x_val: desk.x / imageDims.width, // Store as a ratio of the image width
              y_val: desk.y / imageDims.height, // Store as a ratio of the image height
              radius: desk.radius / Math.min(imageDims.width, imageDims.height), // Store as a ratio of the smallest dimension
            })),
          };
        }),
        desks: desks
          .filter(
            (desk) =>
              !zones.some(
                (zone) =>
                  desk.x >= zone.x &&
                  desk.x <= zone.x + zone.width &&
                  desk.y >= zone.y &&
                  desk.y <= zone.y + zone.height
              )
          )
          .map((desk) => ({
            name: desk.name || `Desk in Room ${roomId}`,
            x_val: desk.x / imageDims.width, // Store as a ratio of the image width
            y_val: desk.y / imageDims.height, // Store as a ratio of the image height
            radius: desk.radius / Math.min(imageDims.width, imageDims.height), // Store as a ratio of the smallest dimension
          })),
      };

      await axios.put(`/rooms/${roomId}/annotations`, annotationsData);

      const updatedRoom = await axios.get(`/rooms/${roomId}`);
      dispatch(setShapes(updatedRoom.data.shapes));
      handleRefreshPage();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

and finally CustomerAnnotationCanvas.jsx (this is where I display the saved annotation after receiving them from the DB):
const CustomerAnnotationCanvas = () => {
  const { image: imageSrc, shapes } = useSelector((state) => state.annotations);
  const [imageDims, setImageDims] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  // Dynamically calculate canvas dimensions based on screen size
  const canvasWidth = useBreakpointValue({
    base: window.innerWidth * 0.9,
    md: window.innerWidth * 0.65,
  });

  const canvasHeight = useBreakpointValue({
    base: window.innerHeight * 0.5,
    md: window.innerHeight * 0.75,
  });

  const scaledShapes = shapes.map((shape) => {
    const scaleX = imageDims.width;
    const scaleY = imageDims.height;

    return {
      ...shape,
      x: shape.x * scaleX,
      y: shape.y * scaleY,
      width: shape.width * scaleX,
      height: shape.height * scaleY,
      radius: shape.radius * Math.min(scaleX, scaleY),
    };
  });

return (
    <Box
      border="1px"
      borderColor="gray.200"
      borderRadius="md"
      overflow="hidden"
      boxShadow="sm"
    >
      <Stage width={canvasWidth} height={canvasHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <AnnotationImage
            imageSrc={imageSrc}
            canvasWidth={canvasWidth}
            canvasHeight={canvasHeight}
            setImageDims={setImageDims}
          />
          {scaledShapes.map((shape, index) => (
            <CustomerShapeRenderer
              key={index}
              shape={shape}
              deskColor={getDeskColor(shape)}
            />
          ))}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </Box>
  );


You most likely have a bug in your calculations. This is not a Konva or canvas issue. Re-check your assumptions. You might want to consider not working so hard. If you manipulated the stage.scale() to handle the resize then you would not need to re-apply the relative positions of the shapes since they would not have moved.
